# Configuring a new ethereum network, using geth and PoA as consensus

Tags: go-ethereum, poa

I am trying to create a PoA private network using geth but I didn't find a good guide lines especially with the PoA addition. I couldn't get a definition and examples of the genesis block configuration.

Is there any resources that is deemed reliable and I can look into ?

Comment: Hi, why don't you have a look at Pantheon, if you don't absolutely have to use Geth or you are open to try another client, you can have a look at our doc site PoA (Clique and IBFT2.0) tutorials : https://docs.pantheon.pegasys.tech/en/latest/Tutorials/Create-IBFT-Network/

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you have a look [here](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8).

Comment: I truly have a real problem with medium tutorials, long and not useful. I need more of a reference than a simple hello world tutorial.

Comment: I would actually take the time to read what I gave you. I used it personally to set up a PoA Private Network for a real working proof of concept. and it worked.

Comment: I am in fact, doing so. I'll see what I get in the end.

Comment: I must say it was quite the waste of time. no offense intended.

Comment: What feedback comments would you make about this Medium Geth PoA tutorial ? What would you like to see written differently, removed or added ?